# Как сделать бесконечное повторение условия if, пока переменная boolean не будет равна true?

Tags: java, if, for

Вроде бы там должен использоваться цикл for. Но как именно это реализовать? Вот код:

```
if (usersel.nextLine().equals("Начать игру")) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int num = random.nextInt(30);
        System.out.println("Игра началась! Бот загадал число от 1 до 30. 
Угадай его!");
        Scanner usernum = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (usernum.nextInt() == num) {
            System.out.println("Вы отгадали! Браво!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Попробуй ещё раз! Неправильно!");
            boolean otvet = false;
        }
        for (???)
       }
   }
```

Comment: `while` https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B_%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0_for,_while,_do_..._while

Comment: Текст на той странице отсутствует, это раз. Два - сложно объяснить как это устроить?

Comment: А в чём идея использовать именно if если для этого предназначена другая функция?

Comment: Я новичок. И по моему if тут в самый раз!

Comment: @ДанилПереверзев Я даже не знаю что тут можно объяснить `while(условие-такое-же-как-вы-бы-написали-в-if) { ... }` будет выполняться до тех пор пока это условие будет истинно. Так что замена слова if на слово while сделает именно то, о чем вы спросили. Да, ссылка битая получилась, найдена в гугле по запросу "java while".

Comment: Без обид, но учите матчасть,для того чтобы использовать if для циклов нужно иметь веские причины, это можно сделать с помощью операторов break и continue , но это очень и очень плохая идея

Comment: Вы как-то накинулись, но похоже даже не разобрались в проблеме. Он ничего не нарушил, написал вопрос и прикрепил код, почему такая агрессия? Он же не попросил написать за него лабу

Comment: Да это не агрессия, я тоже нелюблю учить матчасть, но это НАДО делать, а то иногда долго гуглишь как это сделать и всё равно не до конца понимаешь что ты сделал, а прочитаешь книжку и сразу всё становится ясно, и понимаешь какой глупый и банальный вопрос ты задал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо несколько переработать ваш код, один из вариантов:

```
boolean otvet = false;
while(!otvet){
    if (usernum.nextInt() == num) {
        System.out.println("Вы отгадали! Браво!");
        otvet = true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Попробуй ещё раз! Неправильно!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while(usernum.nextInt() != num) System.out.println("Попробуй ещё раз! Неправильно!");
System.out.println("Вы отгадали! Браво!");
```